# XCODE OC/C++ ,more than 2 files ,duplicate symbol

Tags: c++, ios

when add >= 2 .mm(objective-c/c++) files,compile succ ,but in the linking, 
error is " duplicate symbol xxxxx"
but when only one .mm file , will succ.
I dont know why?
the .mm is right;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iFpe.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell certainly the reason, because we don't see the code. Linker says that you have something declared twice, you should remove other declarations of the same symbols.